# How to add columns if a neighbor does not exist in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that looks like this:

```
estimate  | actual | name
   10     |    1   | Bob
   20     |    9   | Sue
   30     |        | Bob
   40     |    3   | Sue
```

How can I get a sum of where the name is "Bob", and the sum of the actual column if it exists, but if not use the estimate column instead (i.e. 1 + (blank -> 30) => 31)

I keep running into issues with mismatched range sizes - is there any way to do this in one formula without adding lots of "dummy" columns (i.e. if actual , actual , else estimate) and so on? or without needing to create a "Bob" column and always check against that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with two `sumifs` formulas:

```
=sumifs(B2:B, C2:C, "Bob") + sumifs(A2:A, C2:C, "Bob", B2:B, "")
```

The first adds "actual" quantities (column B) where C is "Bob". The second adds "estimates" (column A) where C is "Bob" and B is blank.